# hello there, im jpose75 and i having problems with my code, now the ennucienment:

Tags: python

You are a big fan of television and don't like to watch just one channel at a time. You are constantly switching between different channels, zapping. Your dog tried to eat the remote control and unfortunately partially destroyed it. Now you only have two buttons to change channels: one for the next channel and one for the previous channel.
Your television has 100 channels, conveniently numbered from 0 to 99 and cyclical, that is, if you are on channel 99 and press next, you will reach channel 0 and vice versa.

task
You must write a program that receives two numbers, one on each line: target channel and current channel. The program will print the minimum number of times the buttons must be pressed to get from the current channel to the target channel, indicating X times up or "Y times down", depending on which is less. (X and Y being the number of times). To simplify this exercise, X and Y will never be equal."

code:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = (y - x)
w = (x - y)
ciclop = (99 - x) + y + 1 #si el ciclo no supera 99
ciclon = x + (99 - y) + 1 #si el ciclo supera 99
#print(ciclop, ciclon)

if y > x and z < 50:
  print(abs(100 - ciclon), "veces abajo")
elif y > x and z > 50:
  print(abs(ciclon), "veces arriba")
elif x > y and w > 95:
  print(ciclop, "veces abajo")
elif x > y and z < 50:
  print(abs(ciclon - 100), "veces arriba")
elif x > y and z > 50:
  print(abs(100 - ciclon), "veces arriba")]
```

Comment: x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = (y - x)
w = (x - y)
ciclop = (99 - x) + y + 1 #si el ciclo no supera 99
ciclon = x + (99 - y) + 1 #si el ciclo supera 99
#print(ciclop, ciclon)

if y > x and z < 50:
    print(abs(100 - ciclon), "veces abajo")
elif y > x and z > 50:
    print(abs(ciclon), "veces arriba")
elif x > y and w > 95:
        print(ciclop, "veces abajo")
elif x > y and z < 50:
    print(abs(ciclon - 100), "veces arriba")
elif x > y and z > 50:
    print(abs(100 - ciclon), "veces arriba")

Comment: And what happens?  Does this code work?  What is your question?  You don't really need all that code.  The answer is `abs(x-y)` unless that value is > 50, in which case it is 100 minus that.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].